# Create database with forest replicas

Tags: marklogic

I want to create a database with the replicas attach for failover:

I can at the moment only create the DB then detach and delete the forest, then in the next command create the forest replicas.

CREATE DB

```
curl -v -X POST  --anyauth -u us:pw http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis \
--header "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"rest-api": { "name": "testdb", "database": "testdb", "modules
database": "testdb-modules", "forests-per-host": 2 } }'
```

CREATE REPLICA

```
 curl -s --anyauth --user us:pw -X POST -i -H 'Content-type:      application/json' http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/forests -d '
{ 
"forest-name": "testdb-8", 
"host": "ip-10-10-30-243.eu-west-1.compute.internal",  
"database": "testdb", 
"forest-replicas": { 
 "forest-replica":[ 
    { "replica-name": "testdb-8-Rep01", "host": "ip-10-10-31-238.eu-west-1.compute.internal" },  
    { "replica-name": "testdb-8-Rep02", "host": "ip-10-10-32-253.eu-west-1.compute.internal" }  
]
} 
 } '
```

Also is there a 'curl' to detach a forest from a database.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

"is there a command to detach a forest form a database"

I think you probably get what you want from this REST [endpoint](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/forests/[id-or-name]/properties):

The page is quite complete in explaining the items you can control.

Perhaps this pattern: [get](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/forests/[id-or-name]/properties) -> modify -> [put](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/forests/[id-or-name]/properties)

Comment: Thanks, Looked through this earlier, its possible to create and add replicas and association, but not the detach from database,  a forest under this requires a positive number - else the command fails.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted: Thanks David.

Had to enabled = false then true

As seen in the link below:

```
 curl --anyauth --user us:pw -X PUT -d @./forest-properties.xml \
-i -H "Content-type: application/xml" \
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/forests/testdb/properties
```

The database this then detached from the forest and so you can now delete the forest.

```
curl -X DELETE --anyauth --user us:pw  http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/forests/testdb?level=full
```

Comment: Sounds like you've figured out the problem -- please mark an answer as "accepted" so that people looking at this question know you don't need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS BETTER

curl --anyauth --user user:password -X POST -i \
    -d "state=attach" -d "database=Documents" \
    -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/forests/example